# Connection pool API for Tomcat version 3.0 and jdk1.5

Tags: java

I need to do connection pooling for my JSP program. I'm using Tomcat version 3.0 and jdk1.5. Please suggest me an API for connection pooling that is compatible with both.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but... "*Tomcat 3.0.x. (initial release) 1999*" - have you considered upgrading?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz i am asked to do it using Tomcat 3.0. Can i still get the best answer?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's just that you'll more likely get an answer for newer versions. But seems like [documentation for 3.3](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/serverxml.html) is still available (if you are talking about HTTP connection pooling). For database connection pooling you'll find plenty of libraries, e.g. BoneCP.

Comment: another pooling library is apache commons pool (http://commons.apache.org/pool/).